# Angular-AG Grid Enterprise : agSetColumnFilter applyMiniFilterWhileTyping

Tags: angular, filter, ag-grid

I am trying to implement AG Grid Enterprise filter feature `applyMiniFilterWhileTyping` configuration. I have the below configuration in my column.

```
 {
        field: 'country',
        filter: 'agSetColumnFilter',
        filterParams: {
            applyMiniFilterWhileTyping: true,
        },
 }
```

But when I type inside mini search filter, the grid data is not filtering only filter list get updated.

Note : I am using Angular : 5.2 with ag-grid enterprise 19.0.0.

Do I need to upgrade angular/ag-grid?

Can you please help on this issue?

Thanks
Saravanan

Comment: Whats the error? Where is the code?

Comment: I didn't get any error in the console, grid data is not filter when i type.  This is the column configuration i have it. { field: 'country', filter: 'agSetColumnFilter', filterParams: { applyMiniFilterWhileTyping: true, }

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade your ag-grid version, note that this feature was released as part of version 23.2.0 as displayed in the [Changelog](https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-changelog/):

> AG-3709   Feature Request 23.2.0  Allow the mini filter in the set filter
> to be applied as the user types (without requiring the Enter key to be
> pressed)

I'd recommend just upgrading to the latest version, but if that's not possible then upgrade to version 23.2.0. Note that you will also need to upgrade your angular version accordingly based on this [compatibility chart](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid/getting-started/#ag-grid--angular-compatibility-chart)

Comment: Thank you Shuheb Ahmed for your help. I will upgrade and test it.